# Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException Response message during load test in JMeter

Tags: java, exception, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to do a load test with **1500VU** in **JMeter** but I am **NOT** able to ramp up more than **1000VU**.

I did some R&D and used two LGs (LG1 with 2 cores CPU and LG2 with 4 cores CPU) and I observed using LG1, I am able to ramp up upto 1000VU with 100% CPU usage(no exceptions), but LG2 starts throwing "**Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException"** even after 600VU.

Even though the config is high for LG2 than LG1, LG1 is performing better.

Can anyone help to answer below two issues:

1. Why LG2 is throwing BindException and what's the solution for that?
2. Why LG2 with 4core is not able to ramp up more than LG1 with 2core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to run JMeter on Windows. If this is the case consider the following steps:

1. Increase [ephemeral ports range](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.1?topic=listener-windows)
2. Decrease the [maximum time the connection spends in TIME_WAIT state](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=system-recycling-tcp-connections-microsoft-windows-operating)
3. Increase the maximum number of network connections if it's below 200

If you cannot do any of these due to lack of administrative permissions - the only option would be get more machines and run your JMeter test in [distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: 2nd option worked! Thanks @dmitri